# Adding colorscale to plotly

Tags: r, colors, plotly

I am trying to plot a 3d frequency map, which works fine.  Later, I want to create a colorscale for the Z axis.

I tried this:

```
intensity = seq(0,30, length=31)
colorscale = list(
  c(0, 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'),
  c(15, 'rgb(247,255,0)'),
  c(30, 'rgb(255, 0, 0)')
)

p<-plot_ly(data = d_long, x = ~i_DiaAlerta, y = ~variable, z = ~value, type="mesh3d", 
           intensity = intensity,
           colorscale = colorscale,
           showscale = TRUE)

p
```

It produces this plot:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onfjN.png)

The color scale is wrong and the plot is alwyas white
My d_long figure looks like this:

head(d_long)

```
  i_DiaAlerta variable value
1         188        1     4
2         189        1     5
3         190        1     1
4         191        1     3
5         192        1     0
6         193        1     0
```

Comment: According to the documentation, I think it also needs the `color ` argument.

Comment: @MLavoie This was taken from an example (https://plot.ly/r/3d-mesh-plots/), but even adding the argument: color = c(0, 10, 20, 30)
It was the same thing

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass the `colors` argument:

```
d_long <- data.frame(
   i_DiaAlerta = runif(30, min = 0, max = 30),
      variable = runif(30, min = 0, max = 30),
         value = runif(30, min = 0, max = 30)
)


p <- plot_ly(data = d_long, x = ~i_DiaAlerta, y = ~variable, z = ~value, type="mesh3d", 
           intensity = ~value,
           colors = colorRamp(c(
             rgb(0, 255, 0, max = 255),
             rgb(247,255,0, max = 255),
             rgb(255, 0, 0, max = 255)
           )),
           showscale = TRUE)

p
```

Answer (score 1):

A working alternative, using colorscale, which needs a thresholds vector (0 to 1) of equal length to the colors vector.

```
  library(plotly)
  
  d_long <- data.frame(
    i_DiaAlerta = runif(30, min = 0, max = 30),
    variable = runif(30, min = 0, max = 30),
    value = runif(30, min = 0, max = 30)
  )
  
  thresholds_colors = seq(0, 1, length = 3)
  colors = c('rgb(0, 255, 0)', 'rgb(247,255,0)', 'rgb(255, 0, 0)')
  
  intensity = seq(0,30, length=31)
  p <- plot_ly(data = d_long, x = ~i_DiaAlerta, y = ~variable, z = ~value, type = "mesh3d", 
               intensity = intensity,
               colorscale = list(thresholds_colors, colors),
               showscale = TRUE)
  
  p
```